# Which data type is equal to bit in the databricks sql

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

Column_name bit in mssql

When creating table in the databricks bit data type is not supported
Which data type can I use

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no `bit` type on Databricks, so you either can use `boolean` type ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/data-types/boolean-type.html)) or maybe `tinyint` ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/data-types/tinyint-type.html))